# Latex: bold numbers with \num

Tags: latex

I'm trying to write in bold some numbers expressed in scientific notation (using \num).

What I've been trying is:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\textbf{\num{1.34e+2}}
$\mathbf{\num{1.34e+2}}$
```

but none of them seems to work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without updating siunitx, it can be done in the following way:

```
\num[math-rm=\mathbf]{1.34e+2}
```

Comment: Good answer, it is more elegant and preferrable way to control font typesettings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `text-series-to-math` and `propagate-math-font` to make siunitx use the font series from the surrounding material.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\sisetup{
text-series-to-math = true ,
propagate-math-font = true
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\num{1.34e+2}}
$\mathbf{\num{1.34e+2}}$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get en error: package siunitx error unknown option 'text-series-to-math' and the same for the other one. I'm using Overleaf

Comment: @Dario Then you are using an outdated version of siunitx. A lot of the names changed from version 2 to 3

Comment: How can I solve the issue? I'm using Overleaf, do I need to install something?

Comment: AFAIK overleaf is currently in the last stages to test texlive2021, they should soon again provide a not completely outdated installation.

Comment: There's no way to solve the issue before the update? Any other way to write those numbers in bold?

Comment: You can track down a local tex installation and upload the files from there to your overleaf project, or go to https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx and build them from their sources or track down an old user manual for version 2 and look up the former names